# Which Membership and Role Provider methods should I override for Authorize attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider, authorize-attribute

To use `[Authorize]`, `[Authorize(Roles="")]`, `[Authorize(Users="")]` attributes, which methods should I override in MembershipProvider and RoleProvider?

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    // which methods are required?
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    // which methods are required?
    ...
}
```

Any suggestion, article, tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the following methods in order for `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` to work.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{    
   public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
   {            
   }

   public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
   {           
   }
}

public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
   public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
   {
   }

   public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
   {
   } 
}
```

OR if you just want the `Authorize` filter to work, you can simply [create Principal object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.aspx) by yourself.

Comment: Yes, `GetUser` is not required, although `ValidateUser` is a must.